# How can I insert 2 images in one image view in Android switch the images every 5 seconds

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to create a banner in Android with two different images in one ImageView, every 5 seconds the images should alternate one after the other.

Comment: if you mean to see it some thing like slide show. Check out View Pager http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: you want it like gif animation.

Answer (score 1):

use 2 imageviews,and set images to that imageview and bydefault make imageview2 as gone after 5 seconds make imagevew1 as gone and imageview2 as visible and viceversea for every 5 sec

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) like so:

```
public static class MyBannerView extends View
{
   private int width;
   private int height;
   private Bitmap bitmap;

public RenderView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

public RenderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public RenderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        //anything you might need here
    }

    //This method is called when the View changes size like on rotation
    protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
    {

    width = w; //this will let you keep track of width and height should you need it.
    height = h;

    }

    protected void updateMyBanner(Bitmap b)
    {
     bitmap = b;
     invalidate(); // This will force your view to redraw itself;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);       
            //there are four different methods for drawBitmap pick the one that
            // suites your needs the best
            canvas.drawBitmap(params which will include bitmap) 

        }

}
```

Now you place this view in your layout in some way and you will call updateMyBanner(Bitmap b) with your bitmap every 5 seconds or whatever. You can create an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to handle this, or you can use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) object and create a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) which will call that.

It is important to remember that you can only touch the UI through the main activity thread, so if you chose to use a thread for this, you will need to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) on the main thread to actually preform the update.